# Get last 10 search crawl logs sharepoint powershell

Tags: search, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I want to get last few crawl log details of all of my content sources through powershell.

Basically, its the search service application -> crawl logs -> crawl history -> for any content source I would like to get last 5 logs. I am not sure which direction I should proceed to get this data:When i say logs, I mean this data

Content Source  Crawl started   Crawl completed Crawl duration  Type    Successes   Warnings    Errors  Top Level Errors    Deletes Not Modified    Security Updates

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing what you can do is export the crawl logs as a csv through the powershell script as mentioned here :-
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloshm/archive/2009/03/31/how-to-programmatically-export-the-crawl-history-to-a-csv-file-in-powershell.aspx

Once exported , just fire up Excel and filter the last five. Its rather more flexible working with a csv in excel as you will get many other filter options over your log file.

Comment: Thanks Moss for replying. I want some kind of monitoring system which just emails me top 5 logs from all my content sources . I don't want to waste my time daily exporting it and then editing it in excel.

Comment: CrawlHistory class is Obsolete, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.crawlhistory.crawlhistory%28v=office.14%29.aspx..Any guess for SP2010.

Comment: This post makes more sense, which i have tested and seems to be working as expected.
http://cameron-verhelst.be/blog/2014/06/13/powershell-search-crawl-history/

Comment: what you will give for the url ?